# How to decode payload and get value inJWT payload

Tags: android, jwt

I want to retrieve the value on the JWT payload, the token I get from the login result. When I tried the token I sent it to the server, it was invalid, the case turned out that the backend server had no code for the authenticate token. As a result, I have to decode and claim the token to get the value "id", "username" and "email".

I have tried using the *jwt.io* libraries as well as other libraries that didn't work either. Is there another alternative for me to be able to get the value id, username and email in other ways?

The JSON response of Login API.

[image]

The token:

```
eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciOiJITUFDLVNIQTI1NiJ9.eyJpZCI6IjQ3NiIsImVtYWlsIjoiZHdpZml0cmlAZXhhbXBsZS5jb20iLCJtc2lzZG4iOiIwODk3MjIzNTQ5NjIiLCJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImR3aWZpdHJpIiwicHJvZmlsZSI6eyJpZCI6IjI5MyIsImlkX2dlb2RpcmVjdG9yeSI6bnVsbCwiZnVsbG5hbWUiOiJkd2lmaXRyaSIsIm51bWJlciI6IjY5MDkzNyJ9fQ.cmPcQKouBSz_RVFUDWBE4-kDqard-ZfD5T0wBloOlGQ
```

The code for decoding the token.

```
DecodedJWT jwtIdent = JWT.decode(token);
Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "this decode" + jwtIdent, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: so why didn't decode work? Any errors? Decoding is quite simple, as it's just base64url encodig. After decoding you get a JSON that you can convert into an object. So for decoding you don't need a specific JWT lib. One thing I don't understand is: why can't thebackend verify the token and why you have to decode it in frontend when backend can't verify it? Who created the token?

Comment: Yes, I also don't understand why the backend that I use can't verify the token. before I tried the token I sent it to the server but there was no response.

I think it's a backend maker error for not verifying the token.

Therefore I have to decode the token so that it can become an object value @jps

Comment: i've used it using base64 decode but it didn't work @jps

Comment: you have to decode the parts (header, payload) separately, not the whole token at once. I decoded it on https://jwt.io and noticed there is a non-standard value for `alg`in the header ("alg": "HMAC-SHA256").  Usually it should be HS256. That could be the reason for the failed verification on the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soved Work with

```
                token = sharedPrefManager.getSPToken();
                try {
                    decoded = JWTParser.decoded(token);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```